# jQuery sortable connecting two lists where only 1 should be sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to do a setup where you can move from A to B and B to A, but only sort in B.

```
$("#B, #A").sortable({
  connectWith: ".sec-sorter",
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.sender == null && ui.item.parent().is($(this))) {
        alert('LALALA');
    }
  },
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    //alert($(ui.item).attr("id") + ' from #' + ui.sender.context.id + ' was dropped     in #' + this.id);
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

This works great, except that #A is still sortable. How could i prevent A from being sortable, yet still connected with B ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two sortables say `A` and `B`. You can hide the placeholder in `A` and cancel the sort inside `A`, giving the impression that it's not sortable, as follows:

CSS:

```
#sortable1 .ui-sortable-placeholder { /*placeholder in A*/
  display:none !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable ",
  revert: 0,
  stop: function (e, ui) {
    if (ui.item.parent().is(this)) $(this).sortable("cancel");
  }
});

$("#sortable2 ").sortable({ // sortable B
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable "
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dz1vmekv/1/)</kbd>